# Pure CSS Way to style radio button group when none of the radio buttons are checked?

Tags: html, css, radio-button

Is there a pure CSS way to style a group of radio buttons such that they look a certain way when none of them are checked? This would be the default state (for legal reasons) of the radio buttons for a couple questions.

Overall, what I'm trying to do is have two conditions:

1. If none of the radio buttons are checked, show all three radio buttons in full color/opacity
2. If one of the radio buttons is checked, show that button in full color/opacity, but the other two slightly dulled/grayed.

It is easy to do condition #2 using the `:checked` selector. But that by itself will leave all three dulled/grayed in their default state. See the snippet for a very basic example.

I realize this can be done with javascript, and if I need to go that route I will. Just thought I'd see if there was a pure CSS way to accomplish it.

```css
input[type=radio]:not(:checked),
input[type=radio]:not(:checked)+label {
  opacity: 0.2;
}
```

```html
<form>
<input type="radio" name="Question" value="Answer1" /> <label>Answer 1</label>
<input type="radio" name="Question" value="Answer2" /> <label>Answer 2</label>
<input type="radio" name="Question" value="Answer3" /> <label>Answer 3</label>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do this in JavaScript. Alone, I don't believe you could do this in CSS because what you need is for it to check if the `radio-button`s are selected and you can't have that kind of logic in CSS.

Here is some code I have pulled together in JQuery (the easiest way to do it):

```js
$(function() {
    $("#radio1").click(function() {
      $("#radio2Text, #radio3Text, #radio2, #radio3").css("opacity", "0.2");
      $("#radio1, #radio1Text").css("opacity", "1");
      });
   $("#radio2").click(function() {
      $("#radio1Text, #radio3Text, #radio1, #radio3").css("opacity", "0.2");
      $("#radio2, #radio2Text").css("opacity", "1");
    });
    $("#radio3").click(function() {
      $("#radio1Text, #radio2Text, #radio1, #radio2").css("opacity", "0.2");
      $("#radio3, #radio3Text").css("opacity", "1");
    });
});
```

```css
#radio1Text, #radio2Text, #radio3Text {
  opacity: 1;;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<input type="radio" name="Question" value="Answer1" id = "radio1"> <label id = "radio1Text">Answer 1</label>
<input type="radio" name="Question" value="Answer2" id = "radio2"> <label id = "radio2Text">Answer 2</label>
<input type="radio" name="Question" value="Answer3" id = "radio3"> <label id = "radio3Text">Answer 3</label>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I gave a try but I was only partially successful. This is not the correct answer, but it is in pure CSS.

```css
input[type='radio']:not(:checked) + label
{
  opacity:1;
}

  input[type="radio"]:checked + label
  {
    opacity:1;
  }

input[type="radio"]:checked ~ input[type="radio"] + label
{
  opacity:0.5;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="input-group">
<input type="radio" name="Question"  value="Answer1" id="one" />
  <label for="one">Answer 1</label>
<input type="radio" name="Question" value="Answer2" id="two" /> 
  <label for="two">Answer 2</label>
<input type="radio" name="Question" value="Answer3" id="three" />
  <label for="three">Answer 3</label>
  </div>
</form>
```

A code pen of it is [here](https://codepen.io/chandrashekhar/pen/Qggzow).

Answer (score 0):

This isn't quite what you're looking for, because while this styling differentiates between checked and unchecked states, it does so not by opacity but by using different colours. Perhaps you can adapt it to suit your needs.

Hope it helps. [here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/f2373z4f/)

```css
[name=radio] {
  display: none;
}

[for^=radio] {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top!important;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px 15px 0px 15px;
  width: 120px;
}

[for^=radio]:before {
  display: inline-block;
  content: '';
  position: relative;
  margin: 0px 5px -10px 5px;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  background: red;
}

[type=radio]:checked + [for^=radio]:before {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<input id=radio-1 type=radio name=radio />
<label for=radio-1>Answer 1</label>
<input id=radio-2 type=radio name=radio />
<label for=radio-2>Answer 2</label>
<input id=radio-3 type=radio name=radio />
<label for=radio-3>Answer 3</label>
```